# Sorting a file up to a comment in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

Say I have a sort_me.txt file:

```
a
d
b
c
f
g

// dont mix the two sections

a
c
d 
b
```

at the moment, I do the obvious `sort sort_me.txt` and I get:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
d
d
// dont mix the two sections 
f
g
```

Which of course is not what I want, what I want is for it to sort the section before the comment and then the section after the comment separately.

With the desired result as:

```
a
b
c
d
f
g
// dont mix the two sections
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about using `csplit` to split the sections into separate files, but of course there should be easier ways to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

linenum=`csplit -z $1 /^$/ {*}`
count=0
output=''
for line in $linenum
  do
    file=`printf "xx%.2d" $count`
    sorted=`cat $file | sort`
    output="$output$sorted"
    ((count++))
  done
echo "$output"
```

Notice that `csplit` will create a temporary file for each section, so you might update the above script to unlink each of these i.e `unlink $file`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -007 -nE '
    @sections = map [ split /\n/ ], split m{^(?=//)}m;
    say join "\n", sort @$_ for @sections;
' -- file
```

- `-007` reads the whole file instead of processing it line by line (only works if the file isn't huge)
- `@sections` is an array of arrays, outer arrays correspond to sections, inner arrays to individual lines

If the file is too large to fit into the memory, you need to process it line by line, storing only the current section:

```
perl -ne '
    sub out { print sort @lines; @lines = $_ }
    if (m{^//}) { out() }
    else { push @lines, $_ }
    END { out() }
' -- file
```

Answer (score 1):

Without perl you can do it with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=$1

SEPARATOR='//'

LINE_NUMBER=`grep -n $SEPARATOR $FILE_NAME  | cut -f1 -d:`

FILE_LENGTH=`wc -l $FILE_NAME | cut -f1 -d\s`

head -$(($LINE_NUMBER-1)) $FILE_NAME | sort

grep $SEPARATOR $FILE_NAME

tail -$(($FILE_LENGTH-$LINE_NUMBER-1)) $FILE_NAME | sort
```

It searches for the separator line and sort the sections one-by-one. Of course if you have more than two sections it won't work.